# Simctl install can't find Bundle Identifier in .app when installing app in simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcrun, cfbundleidentifier, simctl

When I try to install my app in the booted simulator, like this:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /build/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/foo.app
```

I get the following result:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
```

When I inspect the Info.plist inside the .app, the CFBundleIdentiefier is there and correct.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.bar.foo</string>
```

I am using xcode 6.3.2 on Yosemite

The simulator is booted at installation time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All it was, was a wrong path:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /build/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/foo.app
```

The first forward slash shouldn't be there... as simple as that:

```
xcrun simctl install booted build/iphone/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/foo.app
```

Comment: I should probably make the error message a bit better for that case.  Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Filed under bug nr: 21456832

Comment: Got report that it was fixed in upcoming version of XC, but have not been able to verify yet.